# Creating a table for a show using ID's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Creating a table for a specific show using MongoDB ID's in my Express.js application I'm trying to associate tables with shows using their ID's:

```
export const createTable = async (req, res, next) => {
const showId = req.params.showid;
const newTable = new Table(req.body);

try {
  const savedTable = await newTable.save();

  console.log("Saved Table ID:", savedTable._id);

  const updatedShow = await Show.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: showId },
    { $push: { tables: savedTable._id } },
    { new: true } // To return the updated show document
  );

  console.log("Updated Show:", updatedShow);

  res.status(200).json(savedTable);
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error:", err);
  next(err);
}
```

`findOneAndUpdate` doesn't correctly update the specified show document with newly created table's ID. `showId` and `savedTable._id` are both valid and properly formatted. What is causing this (or suggest an alternative approach to associate tables with shows using MongoDB ID's)?

Comment: What's the returned value of `updatedShow`?